# android Activity intent to a BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, baseadapter

I want to know if it's possible to send several informations by intent from an Activity to a BaseAdapter.

Indeed, I have an application android, and I want to send the mail of the user to an BaseAdapter that contains a listView.

So is it possible ?

I try like this but I have an error : (I send in the onPostExecute() )

My Activity :

```
    public class ParticipateActivity extends Activity {

// Declare Variables
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
ListView listview;
ListViewAdapterTournament adapter;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
static String NOMTOURNAMENT = "nomTournament";
static String NBPLAYERSMAX = "nbPlayersMax";
static String MAIL = "mail";

// To know the main user
public String mail;

// IDs for menu items
private static final int MAIN_MENU = Menu.FIRST;

//php server
private static final String LISTTOURN_URL = "http://10.0.0.35/BD_Projet/liste_tournament.php";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from listview_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_participate);


    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Get the result of mail
    mail = i.getStringExtra("mail");
    System.out.println(mail);

    // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    new DownloadLT().execute();
}

// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadLT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    // Allow to display an circle Bar
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ParticipateActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON ListTournaments Michaël KOZA");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading for tournaments...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        List<NameValuePair> args = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        args.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mail", mail));

        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address (We return just tournaments where there are still places to play)
        jsonobject = JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(LISTTOURN_URL, "POST", args);

        // checking  log for json response
        Log.d("Register attempt", jsonobject.toString());

        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("ListTournaments");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                // Retrive JSON Objects
                map.put("nomTournament", jsonobject.getString("nomTournament"));
                map.put("nbPlayersMax", jsonobject.getString("nbPlayersMax"));
                // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                arraylist.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapterTournament(ParticipateActivity.this, arraylist);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        //intent
        Intent i = new Intent(ParticipateActivity.this,ListViewAdapterTournament.class);
        i.putExtra("mail", mail);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
 }
```

And my ListView :

```
    public class ListViewAdapterTournament extends BaseAdapter {

 // Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

public String mail, nomT;       

public ListViewAdapterTournament(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
    this.context = context;
    data = arraylist;
}

/* Permet de savoir le nombre d'item à afficher dans le liste view */
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView nomTournament;
    TextView nbPlayersMax;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_view_adapter_tournament, parent, false);
    // Get the position
    resultp = data.get(position);

    //receive the mail
    Intent i = getIntent();             //error 
    // Get the result of mail
    mail = i.getStringExtra("mail");

    // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
    nomTournament = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nomTournament);
    nbPlayersMax = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nbPlayersMax);

    // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
    nomTournament.setText(resultp.get(ParticipateActivity.NOMTOURNAMENT));
    nbPlayersMax.setText(resultp.get(ParticipateActivity.NBPLAYERSMAX));


    // Capture ListView item click
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Get the position
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChooseTeam.class);
            mail = resultp.get(ParticipateActivity.MAIL);
            System.out.println(mail);
            intent.putExtra("mail", mail);
            intent.putExtra("nomTournament", nomT);
            // Click on item, on enregistre le joueur dans le tournament et on lui demande de choisir team
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    return itemView;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Mickey74

Comment: You shouldn't use an intent. Just update the adapter connected to the listview. Adapter is not meant to run as an activity, but is a building block for lists.

Comment: And I can send informations at an activity without go to this activity ?

Comment: Not when you are already in the activity that contains the listview that has this adapter set. You can just update this adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Yeah ok, but it possible when I have on an activity to send informations by intent but don't go on this activity with startActivity() immediately? Because If i don't go on the activity, the system remember that I have sent before the informations?

Comment: I don't follow. You can pass information to an activity and  then start this activity, yes. But you cannot use Intent on an adapter. You should make the adapter variable accessible to the place where you have the info to update the adapter. That's all.

Comment: I find a solution to send informations without open a new activity. It's the utilization of Shared Preferences

Comment: You can also generate a singleton to store global variables, however it is best practice to move variables through arguments. But choose whatever fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

To send an informations at another activity without open the other activity, you have to pass by the Shared Preferences.

To send the informations you have to do that :

```
     SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString(MY_NAME, "Mickey74");
    prefsEditor.commit();
```

And to use this informations in another activity to late :

```
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String prefName = myPrefs.getString(MY_NAME, "nothing");
    System.out.println(prefName);
```

The result must to be : `Mickey74`

Thank at all for your help.

Mickey74